# Issue when using WCF service in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, csla

I have a WCF project with CSLA and I have published this service and MVC application in my IIS Server, but it's throwing one error when calling the service from Web app

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

This is my service web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_IWcfPortal" contract="Csla.Server.Hosts.IWcfPortal" />
      </service>
      <service name="Csla.Server.Hosts.Mobile.WcfPortal" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IWcfPortal" contract="Csla.Server.Hosts.Mobile.IWcfPortal" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_IWcfPortal" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IWcfPortal" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have consume this service in my MVC web.config like this.

```
<add key="CslaAuthentication" value="Csla" /> 
<add key="CslaDataPortalProxy" value="Csla.DataPortalClient.WcfProxy, Csla" /> 
<add key="CslaDataPortalUrl" value="http://www.someurl.net/WcfFullPortal.svc" />
```

Then after I have called service directly from my service project, that was working fine.

```
<add key="CslaDataPortalUrl" value="http://localhost:11170/WcfFullPortal.svc" />
```

And also tried with published IP address, that also working fine

```
<add key="CslaDataPortalUrl" value="http://10.4.56.75/WcfFullPortal.svc" />
```

Only problem when I use published host name(http://www.someurl.net/WcfFullPortal.svc). And I have open this URL in by browser that was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just Change `Csla.DataPortalClient.WcfProxy` to `Csla.DataPortalClient.HttpProxy`
and `<add key="CslaDataPortalUrl" value="http://www.someurl.net/WcfFullPortal.svc" />` to `<add key="CslaDataPortalUrl" value="http://www.someurl.net/DataPortal/PostAsync" />`

And also add

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = new Csla.Security.UnauthenticatedPrincipal();
        }
```

in Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 0):

Add  following binding configuration right after the  section in the web.config `<system.serviceModel>` section.

```
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="TheBindingConfig">
               <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ray for your replay.
But this not working for me. It's showing same error.

Comment: when you find a solution，can you share with me？Thanks

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Please find that above.